# PHP print content as it is

Tags: php, printing

I have a textarea

```
<textarea id=view-body ></textarea>
```

that gets a content when an onclick from

```
<a href='#' onclick='popup_view(this)' data-body ='". $rows['body'] ."' >view</a>

<script language="JavaScript">
function popup_view(e) 
{       
    var body = e.getAttribute('data-body');         
    el = document.getElementById("view-body");  
    el.innerHTML = body;    
}
</script>
```

I wanted the content of my textarea to be printed the way it is.
For example the onclick sends

```
<i>Wired</i>
```

my textarea printout

```
<i>Wired</i>
```

but not, and supposed to be like this

*Wired*

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_Editable

Comment: Personally I like [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/EAQRm1) approach for a "works almost anywhere" method, but I'll freely admit it doesn't quite have the pizazz of WYSIWYG

Comment: the more I look at it the more I like @DaveRandom's approach. You could write the contents of the textarea to a div when the contents change. And have a stylesheet which hides / displays the filled div when printing if you don't want it displayed always.

Comment: @PeeHaa The main reason I prefer that over WYSIWYG is because all HTML based rich text editors tend to produce messy markup, and you often end up with nested (and sometimes conflicting) tags when you change the style of some bit of text more than once. The question really is "how techie is your audience?" because I wouldn't want to subject my grandma to having to learn about HTML markup when the old dear has only just got her head around the italic button on the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript innerHTML function will convert text to html form.

You can use textContent function as shown here

http://jsfiddle.net/yWgn7/

In jquery you can use .text() function, but i am not sure about textContent compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a textarea try using a div. If I'm understanding this correctly, the textarea is showing the `<i></i>` and you don't want it to.  Textarea doesn't handle html formatting naturally.

Answer (score 0):

HTML's built in `<textarea>` elements doesn't allow you to style it's contents. What you need is some kind of a [wysiwyg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_editor#Online_editors) editor to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your text-area with any Rich text editor
http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 0):

You must use the htmlentities function to replace special characters with html entities.

```
data-body = "<? php echo htmlentities($rows[' body ']);?>"
```